# Bug ao linkar url que contenha "$"

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Tanto  nessa resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/139140/4995 como no chat, reparei um pequeno bug.

Quando colei uma url da documentação do angularjs, notei que quando a url contém `$`, a conversão automática de url para link bug.

Testando url:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer

Na postagem original, com conversão automática de link, havia ficado assim:

[image: Bug no cifão]

Como poderíamos resolver isso?

**Observação**: Quando estamos escrevendo ou editando o post, parece que a conversão é feita como esperado. Somente na exibição é que ocorre esse problema.

Comment: Post no metão: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32417/dollar-sign-in-url-breaks-link

Comment: @OnoSendai pensei em dar um urlencode no $ para testar. Olha o contexto da pergunta, muita conidicência

Comment: Pois é, exatamente o mesmo use case. =)

Comment: Pode simplesmente usar & e o código do caractere. A mesma coisa acontece com outros caracteres especiais, e até acentos.

Comment: @Bacco edita a resposta do Ono então, só pra ver se funfa :D

Comment: @Bacco cabe uma resposta no " metinha"

Comment: A do @OnoSendai eu arrumei assim: `[http://link_com_$](http://link_com_$)` pq é link automático. Quando é link com [1]: link eu costumo usar `%urlencode` (tem alguns links da Wikipedia com acento em resposta minha em que precisei disso)

Comment: @Bacco problema resolvido, estilo PHP (gambiarra)